# Send Email to more then 1 recipient from script

Tags: python-3.x

i have a file this is the code in the file

```
import smtplib
import sys
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "foo@bar.com"
toaddr = sys.argv[7]

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] =  sys.argv[7]

subject = "Call Recordings Caller: "+ sys.argv[4] + " Time: " + sys.argv[1] + " " + sys.argv[2] + " " + sys.argv[3]
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = "You have a new call recording to listen to \n\nThe call date and time was %s %s %s \n\n The call was from %s \n\nThe call was to %s \n\n\nPlease see the attached file" %(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4],sys.argv[5])

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = sys.argv[6]

recoding_file = "/tmp/recordings/" + filename
attachment = open(recoding_file, "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("username", "encrypted")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

if i am getting in sys.argv[7]  "me@foo.com,foo@me.com"

it will only send the email to the first email in the list

how can i make it so it sends it to all

Comment: By splitting the string into individual addresses and using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make your message a list then run a loop while using sendmail.

```
msg = [recipient1,recipient2]
for i in msg:
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, i)
```